# mime types and sharePoint sites. f4v files windows can not open this file?

Tags: iis, video, file-server

I have about 20 f4v files.  As a test I copied them to a folder, pointed a new iis site to them, add a video mime type and I am able to play them from web browser url.

I'm trying to do the same from sharePoint though a  page viewer webpart. I've modified the iis website for the sharePoint site to have mime type for F4V and created a page viewer webpart pointing to a file share with the files. The files list buy when I click on them I get cannot open this file in IE.

Answer (score 2):

F4V is going to leverage which ever player you have registered for that extension.  I will assume the native flash player. Page Viewer is simply rendering the content in an iframe, and the files are delivered like any other rendered link.  In the absence of any errors you can try the following:

I would load up [Fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/), run it against your IIS site on a successful playback, then do the same in SharePoint and you can compare the outputs.

When going thru the SharePoint attempt, I would look for first if the file is being delivered, if not than you need to start troubleshooting the server delivery. If it is, I would verify the mime type is being transmitted correctly. If for some reason the MIME type is not being transferred correctly, then Flash wouldn't know to open it.